# Regex appending extra string in the start and end of resulting string

Tags: java, regex

I am having string which is in the form of

```
^COBUYE\rtlch\fcs1 \af39\afs20 \ltrch\fcs0 \fs20\insrsid15797378 \hich\af39\dbch\af31505\loch\f39 R-NAME-FIRST COBUYER-NUMBER="1"\rtlch\fcs1 \af0\afs20 \ltrch\fcs0 \f0\fs20\insrsid10175635\charrsid8585274 \cell
```

Now I want to make a string like `^COBUYER-NAME-FIRST COBUYER-NUMBER="1"` from this string. For this I tried this regular expression.

```
\\b(?:\\\\[a-zA-Z]+(-?[0-9]+)? ?)+ ?\\b
```

When I use this Regex like

```
String tag = "^COBUYE\\rtlch\\fcs1 \\af39\\afs20 \\ltrch\\fcs0 \\fs20\\insrsid15797378 \\hich\\af39\\dbch\\af31505\\loch\\f39 R-NAME-FIRST COBUYER-NUMBER=\"1\"\\rtlch\\fcs1 \\af0\\afs20 \\ltrch\\fcs0 \\f0\\fs20\\insrsid10175635\\charrsid8585274 \\cell ";
//String tag = "\\rtlch\\fcs1^COBUYE\\rtlch\\fcs1 \\af39\\afs20 \\ltrch\\fcs0 \\fs20\\insrsid15797378 \\hich\\af39\\dbch\\af31505\\loch\\f39 R-NAME-FIRST COBUYER-NUMBER=\"1\"\\rtlch\\fcs1 \\af0\\afs20 \\ltrch\\fcs0 \\f0\\fs20\\insrsid10175635\\charrsid8585274 \\cell ";
String controlWordRegex = "\\b(?:\\\\[a-zA-Z]+(-?[0-9]+)? ?)+ ?\\b";
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
Pattern controlWordRegexPattern = Pattern.compile(controlWordRegex, Pattern.DOTALL);
Matcher controlWordRegexPatternMatcher = controlWordRegexPattern.matcher(tag);
while (controlWordRegexPatternMatcher.find()) {
    String rtfControlWord = controlWordRegexPatternMatcher.group();
    String replacementText = "";
    controlWordRegexPatternMatcher.appendReplacement(sb, replacementText);
}
controlWordRegexPatternMatcher.appendTail(sb);
```

Then when comes to condition rtfControlWorld becomes

```
String rtfControlWord = \rtlch\fcs1 \af39\afs20 \ltrch\fcs0 \fs20\insrsid15797378 \hich\af39\dbch\af31505\loch\f39
```

and sb becomes `^COBUYE`

Now it again comes to while condition and this time rtfControlWorld becomes

```
String rtfControlWord = \fcs1 \af0\afs20 \ltrch\fcs0 \f0\fs20\insrsid10175635\charrsid8585274 \cell
```

and sb becomes `^COBUYER-NAME-FIRST COBUYER-NUMBER="1"\rtlch`

Why in second time it is starting control word from `\fcs1` instead of `\rtlch\fcs1` ? `\rtlch` is also starting with `\`? How can I make it to work so I can only get  `^COBUYER-NAME-FIRST COBUYER-NUMBER="1"` instead of `^COBUYER-NAME-FIRST COBUYER-NUMBER="1"\rtlch`?

Similarly in case of second tag I get `\rtlch^COBUYER-NAME-FIRST COBUYER-NUMBER="1"\rtlch`. How can I correct it ?

Thanks

Comment: You can try to use a positive lookahead so the cursor will not move

Comment: Your patterns starts with `\b` there is no word boundary before the second `\rtlch` Remove the first `\b` from your pattern and it should work.

Comment: Yes it is working after removing first \b.  But how there is no word boundary. After ` COBUYE` it is `\\rtlch\\` and same after `COBUYER-NUMBER="1"` it is `\rtlch`?

Comment: Try this pattern `\\\\[^\\s]*\\s?`. You can just do this: `tag.replaceAll("\\\\[^\\s]*\\s?", "")`

Comment: The real answer is in the _logic_ that led to going from this substring `R-NAME-FIRST COBUYER-NUMBER` to this one `NAME-FIRST COBUYER-NUMBER` Visually, you may _see_ the result you want. Technically though, it needs rules to get there.